# Payment gateway with coinbase

Tags: php, api, payment, bitcoin, coinbase-api

i have integrated coinbase api in my web app. When charge is created, users are directed to coinbase commerce website to make payment. How do i check if the user has finished paying or not and if the exact amount has been paid. Below is my code

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use CoinbaseCommerce\ApiClient;
use CoinbaseCommerce\Resources\Charge;

/**
 * Init ApiClient with your Api Key
 * Your Api Keys are available in the Coinbase Commerce Dashboard.
 * Make sure you don't store your API Key in your source code!
 */

ApiClient::init("MY API KEY HERE");

$chargeObj = new Charge();

$chargeObj->name = 'Bitcoin Deposit';
$chargeObj->description = 'Testing the payment system';
$chargeObj->local_price = [
    'amount' => '100.00',
    'currency' => 'USD'
];
$chargeObj->pricing_type = 'fixed_price';

try {
    $chargeObj->save();

    // insert into database with status pending
    $queryobject->insertTransaction($_SESSION['user_id'],$chargeObj->id, $amount, $status, $currentTime, 
    $chargeObj->name, $chargeObj->currency);

} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    echo sprintf("Sorry! payment could not be created. Error: %s \n", $exception->getMessage());
}




if ($chargeObj->id) {
    $chargeObj->description = "New description";
    // Retrieve charge by "id"
    try {
        $retrievedCharge = Charge::retrieve($chargeObj->id);
        $hosted_url = $retrievedCharge->hosted_url;
        header('location: '.$hosted_url);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        echo sprintf("Enable to retrieve charge. Error: %s \n", $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually this is handled by [webhooks](https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/#webhooks). _"Coinbase Commerce will send webhook events whenever a charge is created, confirmed or fails"_

Comment: ohh okay thanks. But please, can i test the system without real money? just like how we have test cards for other payment system e.g. stripe. Is there a way to test the coinbase by not sending real money?

Comment: I've never used coinbase so I have no idea how it works. I just guest they used web hooks (since it's common for payment gateways) and did a quick google search. When it comes to questions about what a specific service supports or how that service works, you should read their manual and/or ask in their forums. This site is for when you have issues with your code. It's not a helpdesk for third party services.

Comment: Unfortunately Coinbase does not seem to have any forums for support.  If there are any please note their existence because I would like to be able to ask questions myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use webhooks for this, you can create an endpoint for this. Unfortunately Coinbase does not have a sandbox environment so you are going to need a bit of cryptocurrency in your account.